# "Follow evolution" vs. "follow the evolution"

Tags: grammaticality, articles, definite-articles

Is the article *the* needed in the following sentence and why?

> Want to follow [the] evolution of the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, **the** is required to make the sentence grammatical because a singular common count noun like **evolution** requires the definite article in this context, which describes a particular process of evolution rather than a general process. In sentences like "Evolution occurs in mammoth leaps as well as incrementally", it's the name of a theory or a word denoting a general process and seems to function as a collective noun or a proper noun rather than a common count noun, e.g., **Water flows downhill** and **The water flows downhill** are both grammatically correct, but the first is a general statement and the second is about some specific water.

Answer (score 2):

Normally the article would be required because *evolution* is a particular kind of evolution: *of the project*. In grammatical terms, the use of *the* here is cataphoric. That is, in the words of 'The Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English', 'definite reference is established by something following later in the text, especially some modifier of the noun'.